# JsonPath get array element from inside other array

Tags: jsonpath

I'm just learning about JsonPath.  I'm using jsonpath.com and pasting my below example in there, trying to search based on first name of Donna.

Something similar to:

`$.prizes[?(@.laureates.firstname == Donna)]`

but this does not work.  Is it possible to use a `?(@.)` kind of expression to search for firstname Donna and have the result be:

```
[
  {
     "id": "962",
     "firstname": "Donna",
     "surname": "Strickland",
     "motivation": "\"for their method of generating high-intensity, ultra-short optical pulses\"",
     "share": "4"
  }
]
```

Original data below:

```
{
  "prizes": [
    {
      "year": "2018",
      "category": "physics",
      "overallMotivation": "\"for groundbreaking inventions in the field of laser physics\"",
      "laureates": [
        {
          "id": "960",
          "firstname": "Arthur",
          "surname": "Ashkin",
          "motivation": "\"for the optical tweezers and their application to biological systems\"",
          "share": "2"
        },
        {
          "id": "961",
          "firstname": "Gérard",
          "surname": "Mourou",
          "motivation": "\"for their method of generating high-intensity, ultra-short optical pulses\"",
          "share": "4"
        },
        {
          "id": "962",
          "firstname": "Donna",
          "surname": "Strickland",
          "motivation": "\"for their method of generating high-intensity, ultra-short optical pulses\"",
          "share": "4"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're almost there; try:

```
$.prizes..laureates[?(@.firstname == "Donna")]
```